# How to iterate over a dictionary with tuples?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, iteration

So,I need to iterate over a dictionary in python where the keys are a tuple and the values are integers.
I only need to print out the keys and values.
I tried this:

`for key,value in dict:`

but didn't work because it assigned the first element of the tuple to the key and value and the second to the value.

So how should I do it?

Comment: pls. show some data.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that `for key,value in dict` iterates over keys and values at the same time is false.
You need to do

```
for key in dict:
    print("key: " + key)
    print("value: " + dict[key])
```

or if you feel fancy:

```
for key,value in dict.items():
    print("key: " + key)
    print("value: " + value)
```

if you need both keys in the tuple you can also do

```
for (key1, key2),value in dict.items():
    print("key1: " + key1)
    print("key2: " + key2)
    print("value: " + value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use 
`for key in dict`
and then access the value with dict[key]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
for item in a_dict.items():
   print(item)
```

you will see it print a tuple that is the key and value,  item[0] should be your touble and item[1] should be the value stored under that key.

Answer (score 0):

```
# regarding a proposed edit:
# dict() can be used to initialize a dict from different formats
# it accepts for instance a dict or a list of tuples
# in case of a static dict like below, only using {..} is sufficient
dot = dict({
  ('a', 'b'): 1,
  ('c', 'd'): 2
})

for k, v in dot.items():
   print(k,  " and ", v)
```